# How to reset counter of cart items

Tags: javascript, angular, counter, reset

I modified Angular sample shopping cart app and I cannot reset counter of cart items in correct way.
After submitting the form counter should be zero.

Here is what I managed to do: [the application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gw71r). You can edit my code in any way you wish.

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: It's because the state of the cart isn't properly communicated between the components. You load the items once in the `TopBarComponent` and the length updates because you get a reference to the items in the service. What you should do in my (humble) opinion, is create a `Subject` in the `CartService` which either only emits the number of items in the cart or all the items. Then you can subscribe to that wherever you want in your app. This way you can uncouple your components. Getting one of your components via DI into another component is kind of hacky I think. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gw71r-ksjm5m. You had a tight coupling between card and topbar. I removed it and made it flexible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```js
clearCart() {
    this.items.length = 0;
}
```

I just can't explain you what is happening, hopefully someone can.

Comment: In Javascript objects are passed by reference , so this.item is a object and in this project we are directly assigning this.items to other class variables all are pointing to same reference or you can say same memory location of object.(it's not a correct way to implement , and other answer has done a good job in refactoring ) so when you do this.items.length = 0 ;  then that reference part gets clear ,all other pointing to same location also get's updated. (hope this may help a bit)  (as earlier this.items = [] , points it to new memory location but  others are still pointing to same

Comment: Earlier approach could lead to memory leaks in some implementations.